# Error when Adding weight related configurations

Tags: pallet, rust

I'm in the process of configuring weights for a pallet

```
pub struct GymWeight<T>(PhantomData<T>);

impl<T: frame_system::Config> WeightInfo for GymWeight<T> {

    fn register_members() -> Weight {
        (51_977_000 as Weight)
            .saturating_add(T::DbWeight::get().reads(2 as Weight))
            .saturating_add(T::DbWeight::get().writes(2 as Weight))
    }
```

But I'm ended up in the following error

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `{integer}` as `Weight`
   --> gym/src/weights.rs:105:3
    |
105 |         (51_977_000 as Weight)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object

error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `{integer}` as `Weight`
   --> gym/src/weights.rs:106:45
    |
106 |             .saturating_add(T::DbWeight::get().reads(2 as Weight))
    |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

Imports as follows

```
#![cfg_attr(rustfmt, rustfmt_skip)]
#![allow(unused_parens)]
#![allow(unused_imports)]

use frame_support::{traits::Get, weights::{Weight, constants::RocksDbWeight}};
use sp_std::marker::PhantomData;
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

What version of the Substrate you are using? If it is `polkadot-v0.9.30`+, it may be caused by weight v1.5. The type of `Weight` has been changed. Please refer to [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12138)

You should use the weight in this way:

```rust
Weight::from_ref_time(52_281_000 as u64)
    .saturating_add(T::DbWeight::get().reads(4 as u64))
    .saturating_add(T::DbWeight::get().writes(4 as u64))
```